# Python multiprocessing map using with statement does not stop

Tags: python, python-multiprocessing

I am using `multiprocessing` python module to run parallel and unrelated jobs with a function similar to the following example:

```
import numpy as np
from multiprocessing import Pool

def myFunction(arg1):
  name = "file_%s.npy"%arg1
  A = np.load(arg1)
  A[A<0] = np.nan
  np.save(arg1,A)

if(__name__ == "__main__"):
  N = list(range(50))
  with Pool(4) as p:
    p.map_async(myFunction, N)
    p.close() # I tried with and without that statement
    p.join() # I tried with and without that statement

  DoOtherStuff()
```

My problem is that the function `DoOtherStuff` is never executed, the processes switches into `sleep` mode on `top` and I need to kill it with <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> to stop it.

Any suggestions?

Comment: What exactly are you expecting your `Pool` to do? If I replace `DoOtherStuff()` with a simple print statement it is executed.

Comment: Whatever I put in `DoOtherStuff()` (even `print` statement) is not executed. I simplified my example but my code is very similar, just longer. I have more proc (24) and much more files to process (~2000), maybe it could come from that ?

Comment: Without the files it's a little hard to reproduce, I just changed to content of your `myFunction` to `return arg1`, and then after the `mapping` I print the results using `.get()` what works. `close` and `join` are not needed. Do you have evidence that all your files are processed successfully?

Comment: The files are simple 2D arrays and are all successfully processed (I can easily check that). I am trying now with the `.get()` and will let you know.

Comment: Also I am confused, If I run the same script, with exacltly the same data, without `DoOtherStuff()`, the script works and exit correctly.

Comment: Alright, I think I will close that question and try to identify exactly where to problem is to make it reproducible! Thanks for your help.

Comment: Or you can show us the implementation of `DoOtherStuff()`

Comment: `DoOtherStuff()` does not exists, it's a generic function I put there, but whatever I replace it with, including `print` statements, are not executed. However I'd like to include some not-parallel postprocessing to the script.

Comment: I actually found a solution! I'll reply to my own question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have at least a couple problems.  First, you are using `map_async()` which does *not* block until the results of the task are completed.  So what you're doing is starting the task with `map_async()`, but then *immediately* closes and terminates the pool (the `with` statement calls `Pool.terminate()` upon exiting).

When you add tasks to a Process pool with methods like `map_async` it adds tasks to a task queue which is handled by a worker thread which takes tasks off that queue and farms them out to worker processes, possibly spawning new processes as needed (actually there is a separate thread which handles that).

Point being, you have a race condition where you're terminating the `Pool` likely before any tasks are even started.  If you want your script to *block* until all the tasks are done just use `map()` instead of `map_async()`.  For example, I rewrote your script like this:

```
import numpy as np
from multiprocessing import Pool

def myFunction(N):
    A = np.load(f'file_{N:02}.npy')
    A[A<0] = np.nan
    np.save(f'file2_{N:02}.npy', A)


def DoOtherStuff():
    print('done')


if __name__ == "__main__":
    N = range(50)
    with Pool(4) as p:
        p.map(myFunction, N)

    DoOtherStuff()
```

I don't know what your use case is exactly, but if you *do* want to use `map_async()`, so that this task can run in the background while you do other stuff, you have to leave the `Pool` open, and manage the [`AsyncResult`](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.pool.AsyncResult) object returned by `map_async()`:

```
result = pool.map_async(myFunction, N)
DoOtherStuff()
# Is my map done yet?  If not, we should still block until
# it finishes before ending the process
result.wait()
pool.close()
pool.join()
```

You can see more examples in the linked documentation.

I don't know why in your attempt you got a deadlock--I was not able to reproduce that.  It's possible there was a bug at some point that was then fixed, though you were also possibly invoking undefined behavior with your race condition, as well as calling `terminate()` on a pool after it's already been `join()`ed.  As for your why [your answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59354584/982257) did anything at all, it's possible that with the multiple calls to `apply_async()` you managed to skirt around the race condition somewhat, but this is not at all guaranteed to work.

Comment: Much better solution than mine. I'll keep yours and delte that one. Thanks for the explanations.